# Bash: concenate lines in csv file (1+2, 3+4 etc)

Tags: bash, csv

I have a bash file with increasing integers in the first column and some text behind.

```
1,text1a,text1b
2,text2a,text2b
3,text3a,text3b
4,text4a,text4b
...
```

I would like to add line 1+2, 3+4 etc. and add the outcome to a new csv file.

The desired output would be

```
1,text1a,text1b,2,text2a,text2b
3,text3a,text3b,4,text4a,text4b
...
```

A second option without the numbers would be great as well. The actual input would be

```
1,text,text,,,text@text.com,2,text.text,text
2,text,text,,,text@text.com,3,text.text,text
3,text,text,,,text@text.com,2,text.text,text
4,text,text,,,text@text.com,3,text.text,text
```

Desired outcome

```
text,text,,,text@text.com,2,text.text,text,text,text,,,text@text.com,3,text.text,text
text,text,,,text@text.com,2,text.text,text,text,text,,,text@text.com,3,text.text,text
```

Comment: what do you mean without the numbers?  Your input and output both have  numbers!

Comment: just updated the question. hope its clearer now.

Comment: `xargs -L2 < yourFile` may be good enough...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ pr -2ats, file
```

gives you

```
1,text1a,text1b,2,text2a,text2b
3,text3a,text3b,4,text4a,text4b
```

**UPDATE**

for the second part

```
$ cut -d, -f2- file | pr -2ats,
```

will give you

```
text,text,,,text@text.com,2,text.text,text,text,text,,,text@text.com,3,text.text,text
text,text,,,text@text.com,2,text.text,text,text,text,,,text@text.com,3,text.text,text
```

Comment: Almost there. For me, it cuts out the first numbers but returns 3 lines for the example (1+2 in one line and 3 and 4 in individual lines).

Comment: not possible with the is script, check your line endings, you might have an extra carriage return (`\r`)

Comment: Is it possible to have this taking place for only non-empty lines? It looks like an empty line at the end is part of the Unix standard?

Comment: if you copied a windows file use `dos2unix file` to convert line endings to unix format.

Comment: Not sure where they come from "^M" (did not use any windows files) but found a solution here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206918/trouble-with-horizontial-merge-of-csv-files-under-cygwin paste -d , test1.csv test2.csv | tr -d '\r' > paste.csv

Answer (score 2):

**awk** solution:

```
awk '{ printf "%s%s",$0,(!(NR%2)? ORS:",") }' input.csv > output.csv
```

The `output.csv` content:

```
1,text1a,text1b,2,text2a,text2b
3,text3a,text3b,4,text4a,text4b
```

**----------**

Additional approach (to skip numbers):

```
awk -F',' '{ printf "%s%s",$2 FS $3,(!(NR%2)? ORS:FS) }' input.csv > output.csv
```

The `output.csv` content:

```
text1a,text1b,text2a,text2b
text3a,text3b,text4a,text4b
```

---

3rd approach (for your extended input):

```
awk -F',' '{ sub(/^[0-9]+,/,"",$0); printf "%s%s",$0,(!(NR%2)? ORS:FS) }' input.csv > output.csv
```

Comment: The first solution works well but the second approach does not seem to work for me. Some parts seem to be cut out. To specify. I have some empty fields and dots in some of the text fields. Two sample lines of input: 1,text,text,,,text@text.com,2,text.text,text and
2,text,text,,,text@text.com,3,text.text,text

Comment: @user3550552, because you did not mention that in your question at first time

Comment: @user3550552, update your question with expected result for the **2nd** case

Comment: @user3550552, just replace `$2 FS $3` in my 2nd approach with `$0`

Comment: replacing $2 FS $3 with $0 in your 2nd approach resulted for me in the same outcome as the first solution (did not remove the numbers)

Comment: sorry, just realized there was an error in the updated version. the question is corrected now.

Comment: @user3550552, ok, see my 3rd approach

Comment: Almost there. For me, it cuts out the first numbers but returns 3 lines for the example (1+2 in one line and 3 and 4 in individual lines).

Answer (score 1):

With bash, cut, sed and paste:

```
paste -d, <(cut -d, -f 2- file | sed '2~2d') <(cut -d, -f 2- file | sed '1~2d')
```

Output:

```
text1a,text1b,text2a,text2b
text3a,text3b,text4a,text4b
```

Answer (score 0):

I hoped to get started with something simple as

```
printf '%s,%s\n' $(<inputfile)
```

This turns out wrong when you have spaces inside your text fields.
The improvement is rather a mess:

```
source <(echo "printf '%s,%s\n' $(sed 's/.*/"&"/' inputfile|tr '\n' ' ')")
```

Skipping the first filed can be done in the same `sed` command:

```
source <(echo "printf '%s,%s\n' $(sed -r 's/([^,]*),(.*)/"\2"/' inputfile|tr '\n' ' ')")
```

EDIT:
This solution will fail when it has special characters, so you should use a simple solution as

```
cut -f2- file | paste -d, - -
```